# Как перехватить вывод в stdout при выполнении exec()?

Tags: python, print

Хочу создать в текстовом редакторе среду похожую на консоль Питона.
Могу запускать `eval` и `exec` с фрагментами текстового файла.
Хочу самостоятельно показывать то, что попадает в `stdout` через `print()` за время выполнения этих `eval` и `exec`.

Как это организовать?

В каких редакторах есть *консоли Питона* с открытым кодом?

Answer (score 1):

> В каких редакторах есть консоли Питона с открытым кодом?

Запустите команду **python** без параметров и получите консоль Python

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['ls', '-la']
cmd = ' '.join(cmd)
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
print(out)
print(err)
```